# Why can't I use read -a to break a string into words?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a sample input file called `in` with the following contents:

```
m@m-X555LJ:~/wtfdir$ cat in
asdf1 jkl1
asdf2 jkl2
asdf3 jkl3
```

I now execute:

```
m@m-X555LJ:~/wtfdir$ mapfile < ./in
```

As expected, the variable `MAPFILE` is now an array that breaks the file `in` into lines:

```
m@m-X555LJ:~/wtfdir$ echo ${MAPFILE[0]}
asdf1 jkl1
m@m-X555LJ:~/wtfdir$ echo ${MAPFILE[1]}
asdf2 jkl2
```

So now I want to break the first line into words. AFAIK `read -a arrname` reads a line from standard input, breaks it into words and stores the result in an array called `arrname`. So I type:

```
m@m-X555LJ:~/wtfdir$ echo ${MAPFILE[0]} | read -a words
```

In my mental model, this is what should happen: `echo ${MAPFILE[0]}` echoes the first row of `MAPFILE` (that is, `asdf1 jkl1`) into standard output, but this is piped into standard input of `read -a words`, so `read` should read this line and split it into words and store the result in an array called `words`.

Yet sadly, this doesn't happen:

```
m@m-X555LJ:~/wtfdir$ echo ${words[0]}

m@m-X555LJ:~/wtfdir$
```

Yep. `echo ${words[0]}` prints nothing, while I was hoping it would print `asdf1`.

Why does it happen? And where is my mistake? And how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want

```
read -a words <<< ${MAPFILE[0]}
```

And according to this,
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read
you should always use a "-r", i.e.,

```
read -r -a words <<< ${MAPFILE[0]}

$ echo ${words[0]}
asdf1
```